# how to find out which plugin disable custom field for post

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I tried to enable custom field for my post but it fails to enable. Read about it online that there is an plugin for advance custom field that is causing the issue. But I am not using this plugin. Below is the list of plugins I used. May I know how do I enable back custom field for post? Thank you in advance!

[image: list of plugin]

Comment: Do you mean the custom fields box at the bottom of the Gutenberg editor is missing? Or something else?

Comment: I tried to enable custom field in preference section, but the page reloads and custom field is not turn on

Comment: Deactivate the plugins until it comes back, then you'll know.

Comment: Do you mean under Settings somewhere? Where exactly? I can't find it.